# How to access python tuple element (which has YAML stored into) without indexing or slicing

Tags: python, tuples, yaml

```
        req:
        - &id001
          displayMd:
            custAttr: {}
            descrMp: {en: Req Descr}
            dispNm: {en: Req Name}
            sysAttr: {}
          id: REQ_ID_001
          parameters:
            method: methodname
            contSId: ['321', '1103']
            cType: 1120
        - displayMd:
              customAttributes: {}
              descrMp: {en: Req Descr}
              dispNm: {en: Default}
              sysAttr: {}
          sUCId: AND/HM/UC_CHA_06-03-2019_1385339459
          uCId: AND/HM/UC_CHA
        version: '1.0'
```

Above is my sample YAML. There are 100 YAML sections like this. 
Using the following code:

```
    myvar = list(pullyaml()) #function pulls yaml from source
    datamap = yaml.dump(myvar)
```

Able to pull the YAML sections under separate "- !!python/tuple" tag and in 'datamap' varibale.
So that looks like this

```
- !!python/tuple
  - "!!<some url>\nreq:\n- &id001\n\
    \  displayMd:\n    custAttr: {}\n    descrMp: {en: Req Descr}\n\
    \    dispNm: {en: Req Name}\n    sysAttr: {}\n  id: REQ_ID_001\n\
    \  parameters:\n    method: methondname\n    contSId: ['321', '1103']\n\
    \    cType: 1120\n    customAttributes: {}\n      descrMp: {en: Req Descr}\n\
    \      dispNm: {en: Default}\n      sysAttr: {}\n  sUCId: AND/HM/UC_CHA_06-03-2019_1385339459\n\
    \  uCId: AND/HM/UC_CHA\nversion: '1.0'\n"
```

Now I want to store/pull only 100 "uCId" and text in-front of that i.e [**uCId: AND/HM/UC_CHA**]
How can I do that?

Comment: So `pullyaml` actually does not care about YAML at all and instead just returns the content of the file?

Comment: @flyx yes.. right

Comment: So firstly, your YAML is invalid – `version:` cannot be on a level expecting sequence items. Then, `uCId` is contained inside a YAML sequence, so you will have to do indexing to reach it (I don't understand why *without indexing* is a requirement). *Section* is not a YAML term and it is unclear what you mean by it. It is also unclear whether the structure can have multiple `uCId` values. Finally, the output you show has a tuple but you don't create one in your code. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would also help to know why the number 100 is significant. How would a solution for the single item you show not work for 100 items? Ideally you should provide input with 2 items to show how they are both contained in the input, together with the expected output.

Comment: @flyx What I mean by YAML section, single YAML unit. [The first code section you see is one yaml unit] uCId has only one value. That's Id so it won't be having multiple values. Whenever I print "datamap " ït is converting into tuple.

Comment: And code snippet you see at end of the description is not expected output. It's just a print(datamap). Expected output would be all i.e 100 uCId like "AND/HM/UC_CHA" and so on